# Paragraph tag closes itself when opened

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a news section for my [website](http://ppl.jekoder.com) and when using the following code:

```
<p id="news-container">
  <h1> . . . </h1>
  <strong>big</strong> . . . . 
</p>
```

When inspecting issues I'm getting, it seems to parse as:

```
<p id="news-container"></p>
  . . . same stuff
<p></p>
```

There are no extra paragraph tags inside of the parent ones, and no extra parsing is done using PHP since when inspecting the page source it looks exactly as it should be, but when are element inspecting it's parsed that way, any thoughts?

**PS**: I tried putting the whole paragraph tags in one set but that didn't fix the issue.
**PPS**: I'm using **SCSS** as my CSS compiler, that couldn't mess with the paragraphs though?

Comment: I assume you're not editing the HTML file manually. What CMS are you using?

Comment: Chrome sometimes does this if there are elements within a `<p>`, have you tried another browser?

Comment: @NicholasShanks I edit the file manually but gets ran through a parser (my own parser) which doesn't produce the ending tags as stated when inspecting the source code.

Comment: @ButsAndCats I'll take a gander now sir

Comment: Wow @ButsAndCats, as you said that I changed the `paragraph` to `article` and re-wrote a bit and thanks a lot, mate, saved my ass. :)

Comment: @Jek You're welcome sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<p>` Shouldn't really be a parent element except for `<span>` and other text formatting  tags.

Sometimes browsers (such as Chrome) will close the paragraph when they render it if another element is opened within it.

Comment: So it all comes back to bad practice, how typical! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Paragraphs are block level and are automatically closed by the browser's parser when it encounters another block-level element (the H1 in this case).

What you see in the inspector is the empty paragraph getting closed.

Comment: "block-level" is an obsolete term that was used (but never very well defined) back in the days of HTML 4. HTML 5 introduces a rather more refined set of descriptors for different kinds of elements.

Comment: @Quentin I've just got the hang of HTML 3.0 and now they've upended it with the incompatible HTML 3.2 >:-(

Answer (score 1):

> Paragraph tag closes itself when opened

No.

The paragraph is closed when the `<h1>` start tag is encountered.

It is forbidden to have a heading inside a paragraph, and the end tag for paragraphs is optional.

See [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element) and pay particular attention to the "Content model" and "Tag omission in text/html" sections.

---

Your content looks more like a `<header>`, a `<section>` or an `<article>` than it does a `<p>`.